# Why does BSON type BSON comparison order matter?

Tags: mongodb, bson

When I read MongoDB document, for each operator in query,
for example [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/#op._S_lt),

the document always mention

**For comparison of different BSON type values, see the [specified BSON comparison order](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types-comparison-order).**

I follow the the link to to that page and read the document. I understand what BSON is, but I don't undersand whey BSON comparison order is relevant in this context.

**question**:

What is the use of BSON comparison order? 
 Why it is relevant here? 
If possible, can you please give an example?

Comment: Pretty sure it just has to do with speed. If you can compare integers or booleans over dates or regexes, that'd be more optimal. This is more of armchair speculation than anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is trying to tell you that given two BSON types you are trying to compare - for example a string and an array, how will they be compared? (since one has to be converted to the other)

Taking the example a bit further down in the documentation, assume that you have a collection where all documents have a field `arr` but of different types (some are arrays, some are numeric). You try

```
db.coll.find().sort({arr: -1})
```

Here, Mongo will be comparing all the documents together to decide what order to return them.

The 1->13 list documents which types have a precedence. For example Numbers (#3) has a higher precedence than an Array (#6), and so the Array must be converted to a Number when comparing an Array to a Number.

The documentation goes on to state that the array is converted to a number by selecting it's biggest or smallest element based on the sort order (ascending/descending).

Comment: But I am storing all data in JSON, not BSON. So BSON comparison order is not relevant for me. Is this correct? Is there a JSON comparison order?

Comment: If you are storing your JSON in Mongo, it gets converted into BSON automatically. JSON is the String form , BSON is the binary form. This more efficient, because JSON strings need to be parsed into their corresponding data structures each time you read them - BSON skips this step.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me!

Comment: So when comparing a (9) boolean to an (6) array, the boolean is converted to an array? What you are describing is not stated in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the use of BSON comparison order?

For comparing two values and deciding whether they're equal or whether one is greater or less than the other. All of the values in MongoDB are represented as BSON.

> Why it is relevant here?

Because you're looking at a comparison operator, and you need to know what comparison means. If `$lt` returns records where a given field is less than some value, you need to know *when* the value in the field counts as being less than that value, and when it doesn't. When comparing two values of the same type, the comparison is defined by the semantics of that type (which are mostly intuitive, with some specific details listed below). But comparison and sorting is only useful if *any* two values are comparable, so there's also an ordering on types that defines the result if two different types are compared.

Answer (score 0):

All of the values in MongoDB are represented as BSON. Comparison is needed to set the decide which data should present in which order. When comparing values of different BSON types, MongoDB uses the following comparison order, from lowest to highest:

```
MinKey (internal type)
Null
Numbers (ints, longs, doubles, decimals)
Symbol, String
Object
Array
BinData
ObjectId
Boolean
Date
Timestamp
Regular Expression
MaxKey (internal type)
```

For details please refer :-
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#bson-types-comparison-order